# How to fix "key pair not generated" when generating CSR

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

I was using the process detailed here to generate a SSL cert for tomcat:

[GoDaddy tomcat installation docs](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5239/generating-a-csr-and-installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-tomcat-4x5x6x)

I made a mistake and put the wrong CN name when prompted by the keystore command, and when I tried to start over, I got the error "key pair not generated".

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix it, I simply got rid of the 2 files that the tutorial created ("crt.crt" file and "tomcat.keystore") and then I could start the process over again. And as suggested in the comments, backup your original files before doing this.

Comment: As a (paranoid) word of caution to other people who may come across this post, I'd suggest backing up the crt and keystore files prior to removing them. =)

Comment: a wise suggestion! I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: as a slight aside, you can create the PEM file for this process by following this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5596842/26510